# Css-library in Single Page Application

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I use [Materializecss](http://materializecss.com/) for UI in ReactJS Isomorphic web-application.
To make server-side rendering possible I need to define all variables on server side, including jQuery `$`. And materialize has own functions based on jQuery.

So, if I will import jQuery as module, it will not work for materialize.
If I will import jQuery the regular way - as script in index.html, then server side rendering will be complaining about undefined variables `$`.
If I will do both, then i will get conflicts.

There are [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/materialize-css), but i don't get how can I use it?
Usually, materialize adds global functions. Should i make it global in the root .js file somehow? If so, then how do I do that?

Comment: @Rob, are you sure? I thought, all scripts are being executed in node server for server-side ReactJS rendering –

Comment: @Tushar, sorry, probably i'm using wrong terminology for 'css-library'. I called "css-library" all that included into materializecss.com - from css till js. And in this question i'm referring to js part of this library. What is the correct term?

Comment: Apparently you can now but that is new to me. I also read that a lot of people struggle with it but I wouldn't know. I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
import jquery from 'jquery';
global.$ = jquery;
```